# Axios get call in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

this is my service class

```
getAllList(): Promise<Array<Sample>> {
    return http
      .get('localhost:8080')
      .then(response => {
        console.log("!!!!!!",response.data);
        return response.data.map((sam) => new Sample(sam.sam));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        throw error;
      });
  }
```

this the component class fro where i m calling my service:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.Service
      .getAllList()
      .then((sample) => {
        this.setState((state) => {
          return Object.assign({}, state, { sample: sample.values });
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Model class:

```
export default class Sample {
  product1: string;
  info: {
    product2: string;
    product3: string;
    product4: string;
  };
```

Whats wrong in this code? and can anyone help me with how to print the data which I am getting from API call in component

Comment: Try changing `.get('localhost:8080')` to `.get('http://localhost:8080')`

Comment: that not a issue, I am able to hit the url, and able to see the result on console. but I am not sure whether my service is correctly written or not. I am new to react and i want to print the data in component